# Code to open HTML file in browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

Is it possible have js script open an HTML file in a browser(code to run and html file)? So like the same function as File>Open with>Google Chrome. I'm aware its redundant but I'm just curious to know if its possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that the same as a link? Or are you thinking opening a file from one browser but have the new file open on Chrome?

Comment: please post your requirement so that we can understand it better.

Comment: Please justify your question properly, so we can help you

Comment: I suspect you mean an AJAX request to open externally sourced HTML content within current HTML content, but no way to tell for sure -- you should really clarify.

Comment: Or alternatively you mean just opening a new browser window from within the current one. If so, this is also [absolutely possible](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) in JS.

Comment: Basically, is it possible for me to write javascript code to open an html file.

Answer (score 0):

A hyperlink will take you to a file and open it. You can link to local files with a URL along the lines of 
`file:///home/username/Desktop/cat.html`
If you put a link to a local file on a public website, however, other users won't be able to access it unless they happen to have an identical file path on their computer.

Hope that's somewhere in the ballpark of what you were wondering.